# will_paginate with a variable per_page is loading lazily on test or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm handling the results per page dynamically like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.per_page = GeneralSetting.where(:key => 'default_message_number').first.value
  #...
```

In development env. is working correctly, but if I change `default_message_number` on test or production env., it keeps showing the previous number of records. If I restart the machine, it takes the new changes.
Is there a way to make this query always, regardless of the environment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a Proc.  *not tested*

```
self.per_page = Proc.new{ GeneralSetting.where(:key => 'default_message_number').first.value }
```